# Multiply Array Elements javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, multiplication

I have an Array of numbers:  `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`
I want to get a list like this:  `input_1 = 1, input_2 = input_1 * 2, input_3= input_2 * 4 ..`
With me can i do in javascript?

Comment: Are you asking for ["variable" variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript) or just how to convert this array into another?

Comment: If you want a variable for every element in your array dynamically, that's not possible without `eval` or similar.

Comment: You can do simple for loop with Object.defineProperty like in below psudo code. function creareVariables (array){ let parent =this;array.forEach((el,idx)=>{if(!idx){Object.defineProperty(parent,'input_'+idx, {value:el})} else{ Object.defineProperty(parent, 'input_'+idx,{value:parent['input_'+(idx-1)]*el})}})} warning untested code.. sent from mobile

Comment: Do you have an initial approach that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var output = {};

arr.forEach((item, i) => {
    output[i+1] = i === 0 ? 1 : (output[i] * (i * 2));
});
```

Output

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 8, 4: 48, 5: 384}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep track of the last calculated value and multiply it by the current element.  There are lots of different ways to do that, here is one:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

let last = 1;
const output = arr.map(el => last *= el);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more functional-like implementation using the `reduce` method ([Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)).

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

const result = arr.reduce(
  (resultArr, _, i) => {
    if (i === 0) {
      // base case:
      return [1];
    } else {
      // step case:
      return [
        ...resultArr,
        resultArr[resultArr.length - 1] * (2 ** i),
      ];
    }
  },
  [],
);

console.log(result);
```